# Will resetting the computer account in AD(2003) break the shares?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, network-share

Had a power outage last night, still cleaning up from that. I have a file server that doesn't know it's part of the domain (getting the error: windows cannot connect to the domain either because the domain controller is down). I read that "resetting" the machine account the bring it back into the domain will do the trick.

Since this is the file server for the entire office, I would like to be sure that I won't bork the umpteen number of shares on this server.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried bouncing the server?  Can you resolve the hostname of the Domain Controller from the file server (i.e. `ping your.dc.local`)?

Comment: yup, connectivity is peachy-keen, just no domain access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resetting the machine account won't remove your sharing information.  This info is stored in the registry and not affected by dropping the machine from your domain and re-adding it.  What you'll see once you break the connection to your domain is that any groups/users/computers etc. that you've given access to in the sharing section will become raw SIDS.  Since you're not connected to a domain they can't be translated.  Once you reconnect to the domain all of that information will display properly as it did before resetting the account.

Answer (score 0):

The method of "resetting" the machine account from AD, and pulling the server out of the domain and putting it back in worked like a charm. All of the network shares were there, and all is well.